# When chaining methods can the child method access and use the results of the 'parent' method? (i.e. Object.parent.child)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, method-chaining

**Description**
I've created a `Report` object that has different environments/groups (:live & :demo) which are simply arrays that will be populated with `ReportItem` objects which have the following attributes `:currency, :gross, :net` (And Gross & Net hold Ruby Money objects).

In the `Report.rb` class there are two methods called `add_money_to_net` and `add_money_to_gross` both have a variable I temporarily named `@group`

**Question**
(`report = Report.new`)
What I'm trying to do is is chain methods like this `report.demo.add_money_to_gross(<params>)` if this method is called i would like to have access to `report.demo` (in place of my `@group` variable). Alternatively calling `report.live.add_money_to_gross(<params>)` should let me access `report.live`. Is this possible?

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

**Report.rb**

```rb
class Report
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :demo, :live

  def initialize
    @demo = []
    @live = []
  end

  def demo
    @demo
    self
  end

  def live
    @live
    self
  end

  def add_money_to_net(money)
    add_money(group: @group, money: money)
  end

  def add_money_to_gross(money)
    add_money(group: @group, money: money)
  end

  private

  def add_money(group:, money:)
    item = group.find {|s| s.currency == money.currency }
    if item
      item.net += money
    else
      group << ReportItem.new(currency: money.currency.to_s, net: money)
    end
  end
end
```

**ReportItem.rb**

```rb
class ReportItem
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :currency, :gross, :net

  def initialize(currency:, gross: nil, net: nil)
    @currency = currency
    @gross = gross ? gross : Money.new(0, currency)
    @net = net ? net : Money.new(0, currency)
  end

  def gross=(value)
    @gross = value if @gross.currency == @currency
  end

  def net=(value)
    @net = value if @net.currency == @currency
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what you're trying to do, almost like a command-line pipe operation. And, no, not possible with your approach (or, IMHO, recommended).

Consider the demo method:

```
def demo
  @demo
  self
end
```

The line `@demo` really is a no-op. You're not "returning" anything here, not assigning anything, it's just ... there.  The only thing returned here is self.

Now, you could do something like:

```
def demo
  @group = @demo
  self
end
```

Then make your call

```
report.live.add_money_to_gross(money)
```

And now it should work as you intend. Here, `live` and `demo` act more as state managers, setting the state of `@group` prior to calling the action method.

That said, this is kind of brittle, and requires that you call things in a certain order, and that temporary variable seems like a pitfall waiting to happen. Why? Because calling this:

```
report.add_money_to_gross(money)
```

is a valid call, but shouldn't be unless `live` or `demo` has been called first. No error will be thrown, it will just add to whichever `@group` was set last.

Instead, it would make more sense to me to actually create a new object to encapsulate all of this:

```
class ReportItemArray < Array
  def add_money_to_net money
    item = find_item(money)
    if item
      item.net += money
    else
      self << ReportItem.new(currency: money.currency.to_s, net: money)
    end
  end
  def add_money_to_gross money
    item = find_item(money)
    if item
      item.gross += money
    else
      self << ReportItem.new(currency: money.currency.to_s, gross: money)
    end
  end
  def find_item money
    self.find {|s| s.currency == money.currency }
  end
end
```

Then, in your report class:

```
class Report
  def initialize
    @demo = ReportItemArray.new
    @live = ReportItemArray.new
  end
  def live
    @live
  end
  def demo
    @demo
  end
end
```

Note, the two methods `live` and `demo` are now actually obsolete, since you use `attr_accessor` and they don't return anything special anymore, so you don't actually need to override them, just doing so to be explicit.  The `live` and `demo` objects themselves are still arrays, so should be compatible with the rest of your code, but the `add_money` methods are also attached to these Array objects, so now you can just do:

```
report.live.add_money_to_gross(money)
```

And now by calling `live`, you get the Array, and since the methods are part of that Array object, you no longer need to pass the context, they inherently know it (`group` becomes `self`).  So, calling the method acts on that given array.

Doing it this way removes the possibility of calling `report.add_money_to_gross` (an error will be raised if you do), which is good because the call here needs more context (the group) to complete. This also removes the order-of-operations conflict, as the state is not needed anymore.

A final unrelated note, you may have caught my fix for this above, but your `add_money` method always adds to the `ReportItem`'s `net` even when the original call was made from `add_money_to_gross`.